# How to use form control in UI AutoComplete #1169

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I try to use fromcontrol in this plugin but show error:

ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'country_id'

In [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=zbpqD5) I have Demo project.

I want to register country_id in countryform but doesn't work.

Please can you suggest me any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Label cannot be a formControl because it is not an HTML form control input element and therefore doesn't have a value.  You need to do something similar to this instead 
`<input type="text" formControlName="country_id">`

Comment: Yes, but how to use it? I try to change Label to input but autocomplete doesn't work. Can you modify my Demo project please?